# how do I play formats other than mp4 and mov with xcode objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, sdk

I want to be able to play other formats in xcode (objective-c) Could someone give me a few pointers.

Currently I can only play `.mov` and `.mp4` files. I'm using the MediaPlayer framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the MPMoviePlayerController docs:

**Supported Formats**

This class supports any movie or audio files that already play correctly on an iPod or iPhone. This includes both streamed content and fixed-length files. For movie files, this typically means files with the extensions .mov, .mp4,.mpv, and .3gp and using one of the following compression standards:

1. H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps. (The Baseline profile does not support B frames.)
2. MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile)
   If you use this class to play audio files, it displays a white screen with a QuickTime logo while the audio plays. For audio files, this class supports AAC-LC audio at up to 48 kHz, and MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3) up to 48 kHz, stereo audio.*

Comment: You only have to pass the URL (or whatever it is) to the mediaplayer. If it is not playable, you will get an alert saying that this video is not playable.